# Difference between ical4j libraries org.mnode.ical4j and net.fortuna.ical4j

Tags: ical4j

We are using *ical4j* through *maven*. While browsing [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=ical4j),
I came across **org.mnode.ical4j** as the most used *ical4j* library in the Maven Central Repository,
and it has the latest versions.
Though there is also **net.fortuna.ical4j**, from a 3rd party repository.

Now I'm confused, since the ical4j web sources and its package structure are suggesting **net.fortuna.ical4j**.
Which one should I use, and what is the difference between artifacts [org.mnode.ical4j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mnode.ical4j/ical4j) and [net.fortuna.ical4j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.fortuna.ical4j/ical4j) ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**net.fortuna.ical4j**

Initial releases of ical4j used this name, however as I don't own the domain fortuna.net it was difficult to release via maven central

**org.mnode.ical4j**

Latest releases use this name, as I control the domain mnode.org

Comment: thanks..... wasn´t clear to me either

Comment: At some point in the future I will switch maven coordinates and package names to "org.ical4j" but for now "org.mnode.ical4j" is still current.