# Add ical4j to a maven jhipster project

Tags: java, maven, jhipster, pom.xml, ical4j

I have a jhipster generated application using maven with java springboot on the backend. I want to add the ical4j library to the project so under the `<dependencies>` tag in the `pom.xml` file I added the lines like explained [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mnode.ical4j/ical4j/3.0.15) . However when I add `import org.mnode.ical4j;` the maven compiler throws an error `package org.mnode does not exist` .
This seems pretty trivial but I don't get what I am missing.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see in the official GitHub repo ([ical4j/ical4j](https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j#configuration)) the correct package to import starts from `net.fortuna.ical4j`. Example:

```
import net.fortuna.ical4j.util.DefaultEncoderFactory;
```

Comment: `net.fortuna` does not exist either. 
Also I imported `org.mnode` because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49891232/difference-between-ical4j-libraries-org-mnode-ical4j-and-net-fortuna-ical4j) question

Comment: Interesting, I tested this before answering and I can use the library without issues with `net.fortuna.ical4j`. Have you run `mvn install` after changing the `pom.xml`? (so maven downloads everything needed)

Comment: I guess I'm missing something really basic. To test I cloned [this](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-maven) git, in the initial folder added the dependency on the `pom.xml`, ran `mvn install`, added the import line on the `greeter.java` class and still have the error.

Comment: Ok so when I write `import net.fortuna.ical4j;` or `import net.fortuna.ical4j.*;` etc it doesn't compile but when I write it like you suggested `import net.fortuna.ical4j.util.DefaultEncoderFactory;` it works. Guess I need to look further into the docs. Thanks

Comment: Note that Java import wildcard only applies to classes. You can't use a wildcard to import all sub packages but rather must explicitly import the packages separately.